# Problem with bootable drive

Tags: usb-drive, bootable

I'm trying to swtich from ubuntu to pop! os. I made a bootable usb drive using "Disks" program in Ubuntu, selecting the voice "Restore Disk Image" with the pop os image. However when I boot my laptop from the usb I just get a blank black screen with an underscore in the top-left corner. I tried to make the bootable usb again and again with other programs but the result is always the black screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a problem with the ISO or the disk image created is not really bootable. You should use another way to write ISO to USB.

Try:

- downloading the ISO image again and reimagining the USB drive
- try [Pen Drive Linux's USB Installer](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)
- use command line `dd` program  (this is a destructive command and wipes the entire USB drive with the contents of the iso, so be careful):

```
 sudo umount /dev/sd<?>
 sudo dd bs=4M if=path/to/input.iso of=/dev/sd<?> conv=fdatasync  status=progress
```

where `input.iso` is the input file, and `/dev/sd<?>` is the USB device you're writing to (run `lsblk` to see all drives to find out what `<?>` is for your USB).

This method is fast and has never failed me.

Comment: I tried it but I keep getting the same black screen. I'm starting to think there is a problem with the .iso file.

Comment: the ISO may simply not be a bootable one, OR the physical USB stick. I assume you followed the official instructions? https://support.system76.com/articles/live-disk/

Comment: Yes, I followed those instructions. However I managed to resolve the problem. It wasn't because of the bootable drive and the .iso. The problem was some boot settings I had to change.